# Retrieving values from reactive mongodb based on Mono

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, okta

I'm building an application based on a Spring gateway & webflux which is integrating with okta as authorization server.

After the frontend is authenticating the user with the okta server, it's getting a token which is must be used per request header as Bearer token.

The end point which I'm developing now is responsible to retrieve all menus related to that authenticated user from reactive mongodb based on the assigned group(s) to that user.

The user's group(s) is/are extracted from the okta JWT token, after that i should inquire to select all menus related to these group(s).

The problem is that I'm not able to use the extracted group(s) name(s) to use it for inquiring from the reactive mongodb

```
@RequestMapping("/menus")
public Mono oauthUserInfo() {

    return ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext().filter(c -> Objects.nonNull(c.getAuthentication()))
            .map(s -> s.getAuthentication().getAuthorities().stream().filter((g) ->g.getAuthority().startsWith("GR_")));
           
    }
```

Accessing the above endpint is retrieving the authenticated user group(s) as below:

```
[
     {
        "authority": "GR_user"
     },
     {
        "authority": "GR_admin"
     }
]
```

My main question is that, How can i use it to retrieve the related menus from my reactive mongodb using 'in' operator and retrieve Flux< Menu >

Comment: Did you already try [`flatMapMany()`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#flatMapMany-java.util.function.Function-)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several trails, finally I achieved my target by extracting the groups names from the Bearer token as below

```
@RequestMapping("/menu")
public Flux<Menu> newEndPoint(){

    return  ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext().filter(c -> Objects.nonNull(c.getAuthentication())).cast(SecurityContextImpl.class)
            .map( a -> a.getAuthentication().getPrincipal()).cast(Jwt.class)
            .map( a -> a.getClaims().get("groups").toString().substring(1,a.getClaims().get("groups").toString().length()-1).replaceAll("\"",""))
            .map( a -> a.split(","))
            .flatMapIterable( a -> Arrays.asList(a))
            .flatMap( a -> customMenuRepository.findByGroup(a))
            ;
}
```

The operations that done on 2nd & 3rd map calls are due to getting the group values as following ["GR_user", "GR_admin"], and I need it like a list of strings without **[** or **"** or **,**